# Android: How to add column title in custom listview

Tags: android

I have a listview and it is properly arranged. I need to add column title. Below i have posted the `display.xml` file which handles the listview arrangments. But there is no title.

Display.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F3CAE5"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Ser No."/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:textColor="#000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

ListView.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/header"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

ShowData.java

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * Created by Akash on 3/13/2016.
 */
public class ShowData extends ListActivity {
    private VivzHelper helper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        VivzHelper empClick = new VivzHelper(getApplicationContext());
        Cursor cursor = empClick.getDetails();

        if (cursor != null)

            getListView().setAdapter(
                    new android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.display, cursor, new String[]{
                            "_id", "Name", "Address"
                    }, new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.add}, 0));


    }
}
```

Comment: try to create listheader.xml and use weight same as display.xml and then set listview.addHeaderView in code.

Comment: Why are you not using tableLayout with ScrollView instead of list view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show a title on top of your listView you could use a header. Instead of including the header layout above your listView, remove it. Leave it  in another xml resource (`header.xml`).

And then when you set the adapter, add also the header to your list like this

```
ListView listView = getListView();
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
listView.addHeaderView(header);
listView.setAdapter(new android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.display, cursor, new String[]{
                        "_id", "Name", "Address"
                }, new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.add}, 0));
```

(I suppose that in your method getListView() you are doing something like

```
private ListView getListView(){
return ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
}
```

This should be your `list.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the header.xml will be another layout where you can define whatever you want to appear on top of your list. If you want three columns

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Street" 
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="#88FF0000"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="number"
    android:layout_gravity="right" 
    android:background="#8800FF00"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="name"
    android:layout_gravity="right" 
    android:background="#8800FF00"/>

</LinearLayout
```

Comment: what should be the contents of header.xml

Comment: Whatever you want to show on top of your list. I think that it should be the layout you were including before if I am not misunderstanding,

Comment: I need to have three column titles, Ser No., name, Place

Comment: so tell me how to form the xml file

Comment: I have updated the code to include your header with three columns

Comment: where to add that piece of code which you have at the top of your answer. those 3 lines. I'm adding them to ShowData.java

Comment: Yes is in ShowData, I will add your code also, one sec

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106339/discussion-between-akashdeep-singh-and-spirrow).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with RecyclerView.Adapter.
RecyclerView.Adapter has getItemViewType() function.

**Example**

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
    if(position == 0)
        return LIST_HEADER;
    else if(position > 0)
        return LIST_ITEM;
    return -1;
}


@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    if (viewType == LIST_HEADER)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.your_header_layout, parent, false);
        return view;
    }
    else if (viewType == LIST_ITEM)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.your_item_layout, parent, false);
        return view;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your Display.xml name to header.xml............

then add layout using include..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/header"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```